# Issue installing my own block in moodle 2

Tags: block, moodle

I'm using moodle 2.

I want to add my own block, so I visited the  [oficial moodle page in order to learn how to add new blocks](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks#Basic_Concepts).

I've created the same code in the page, but when I click upgrade, the page 
http://localhost/admin/index.php?confirmplugincheck=1 appears blank and does nothing.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I've had 1 extra square bracket. The code of the web http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks#Basic_Concepts is ok.